# Multiple language validation handling logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've a form with multiple languages eg: English, German, Chineese. 
Each one contains three fields-

1. select list
2. heading textbox
3. textarea

completed the validation based on everything is mandatory logic.
My requirement has been changed now,

1. If user directly hit submit button without filling feilds everything should be highlighted.
2. If user add a field value of any of the lang, remaining blank fields of respective lang should be highlighted
    eg: User added German heading value, remaining two fields of german only highlighted

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not doing your job. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: am just trying to develop logic thats it. @JonasW. If you are not interested to answer leave it

Answer (score 0):

> You can use depend function in jquery

[How to use jquery validate "depends" on rules other than "required"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039507/how-to-use-jquery-validate-depends-on-rules-other-than-required)

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" class="form-control frm1">
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" class="form-control frm1">
<input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" class="form-control frm1">
```

> In your jquery validation

```
      text1:  {
                            required: {
                                depends: function(element) {
                                    return ($("#text2").val() == "" || $("#text3").val() == "" );

                                }
                            },
                        },

        text2:  {
                            required: {
                                depends: function(element) {
                                    return ($("#text1").val() == "" || $("#text3").val() == "" );

                                }
                            },
                        },


        text3:  {
                            required: {
                                depends: function(element) {
                                    return ($("#text1").val() == "" || $("#text2").val() == "" );

                                }
                            },
                        }
```

> Hope now you understand something,

Comment: wait i will post my answer

Comment: whether you get a solution